# How can I mount or open already dumped mmcblk0?

Tags: adb, linux, mount, partitions

I have dumped a mmcblk0 by adb command. Busybox already installed on my android.

```
adb shell su root busybox cat /dev/block/mmcblk0 > E:\1.bin
```

Now I can not mount this file on windows 10 with default mount option. How can I open it?

Comment: I have tried following video tutorial but result is `broken pipe` or `connection terminated by user`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo5lBWAIb4g

Comment: Could also be the dump is broken as the transfer was made in ASCII mode. Here's what I use for dumping partitions: `adb exec-out "su -c 'cat /dev/block/mmcblk0p24'" > boot.img` – the `exec-out` keeps data from being converted during transfer. Also consider that `mmcblk0` is the "disk", which can hold more than one partition. To check it, you can try opening it with e.g. TestDisk.